# Are "what kind of contractor should I hire" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/277581/what-sort-of-company-should-i-contract-with-to-replace-a-deck-on-a-roof) is just the most recent example of the "what kind of contractor should I hire" questions that we sometimes get here.

Is this considered on topic?

From the [Off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" it seems reasonable, however, it does seem like it's an "open-ended questions" that wouldn't be on-topic.

I'm somewhat divided on this question, and in the past I'm sure I've voted to close a few as "opinion based", others I've voted (or not-voted) to leave open.

Do we have something of an "official" stance on this type of question?

Comment: Truly not an [isolated question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/278321/leak-from-deck-into-house). Based on the overwhelming (lack of) response, I guess there's no "official stance". :(

Comment: I just found DIY meta, here goes...

Comment: Not a "shopping question"?

Answer (score 2):

Though this site is about doing things oneself, I would say hiring a contractor is something one would do oneself. The "Off-Topic" page says:

> if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

If I have a house problem to solve but I'm completely clueless where to start, and I think it's too much for me to do myself, getting expert advice on what professional to hire would seem a good thing.

Comment: Also depends what the problem is.  A roof leak is easy, get a roofer, but a long term roof leak might need more than one type of contractor.